# IIS 8 on Server 2012 "Basic Authentication" is not available as a feature even after installing Role

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, azure, iis-8, http-basic-authentication

I have an Azure VM with Windows Server 2012 on which I use IIS 8.0 to connect to an Azure App Service website. I use Server Management (version screenshot:https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fiqtzw3mgdwd0r/Screenshot%202016-06-02%2015.10.29.png?dl=0). I installed the role "Basic Authentication" per this screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k120gqedqyfzufr/Screenshot%202016-06-02%2015.08.20.png?dl=0

However, in the IIS Authentication GUI, even after multiple server restarts, "Basic Authentication" still does not show per this screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ktz1u77dll49xis/Screenshot%202016-06-02%2015.15.55.png?dl=0

I'm looking to add password authorization for one specific html file on the website. What else can I do to have the "Basic Authentication" available as a feature ? I prefer to use the IIS 8 GUI and not command line.

Comment: Please upload your screenshots using the Serverfault tools, your drop box links don't work. Also your question is confusing, you say you are using Azure App Service, then you seem to mention that you are using a VM running server 2012, app service does not use VM's.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I resolved the sync conflict in dropbox and all should be working now if you don't mind to click the screenshots again. Also I edited my question to clarify that I access my Azure website using an Azure VM on which I'm running Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.0.

Comment: @Sam Did you have a chance to look at the screenshots ?

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it you are trying to apply Basic Auth at the page level, this is not supported. Basic Auth can be applied only at the site, application, virtual directory, and URL level.

Comment: Thanks. You're right that I wanted to target page level but even when I target a directory or the whole site I still do not get the Basic Auth option to show per https://www.dropbox.com/s/baz732ja07o3lwp/Screenshot%202016-06-09%2016.13.13.png?dl=0   Also...any other simple way at server level you can think of that can result in password protecting access to the content of a page or url both from humans and robots ? For robots I know I can set to noindex but is that enough for the purpose of temporarily only allowing "approved" humans to see the content of the page ? .